# Question about inverse in a two-step estimator as a joint GMM-estimators approach

Tags: estimation, moments, matrix-inverse, method-of-moments, two-step-estimation

I'm reading Newey & McFadden - Large sample estimation and hypothesis testing (in the [Handbook of Econometrics, Volume 4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444887660), 1994, page 2178).

My model which I'm interested in has some former estimation done before the estimation of the primary model will take place. Hence the primary model (2nd-step) includes some estimated regressors from the former step (the 1st-step).

In order to account for the first-step variance I followed the approach from Newey & McFadden here the joint GMM-conditions are defined as $\widetilde{g}\left(z,\theta,\gamma\right) = \left[g\left(z,\theta,\gamma\right),m\left(z,\gamma\right)\right]$ where $g\left(z,\theta,\gamma\right)$ are the 2nd-step conditions and $m\left(z,\gamma\right)$ are the 1st-step ones.

The usual asymptotic GMM-variance of the GMM-estimator $\widehat{\theta}$ will look like

$Var\left(\widehat{\theta}\right)$ = $\left(G^TWG\right)^{-1}\mathbb{E}\left(g(z,\theta)g(z,\theta)^T\right)\left(G^TWG\right)^{-1}$

where $g(z,\theta)$ are some moment conditions, $G = \frac{\partial\mathbb{E}\left(g(z,\theta_0)\right)}{\partial \theta^T}$ and $W$ is some weight matrix.

In order to calculate the GMM-variance for the two-step approach I need to derive $G$, $W$ and the derivative of $\mathbb{E}$.

**My Question: I struggle to understand why this is true.**

Let $G_\theta = \frac{\partial\mathbb{E}\left(\widetilde{g}(z,\theta_0, \gamma_0)\right)}{\partial \theta^T}$, $G_\gamma = \frac{\partial\mathbb{E}\left(\widetilde{g}(z,\theta_0, \gamma_0)\right)}{\partial \gamma^T}$, $M = \frac{\partial\mathbb{E}\left(m(z, \gamma_0)\right)}{\partial \gamma^T}$

Then $\widetilde{G}  = \frac{\partial\mathbb{E}\left(\widetilde{g}(z,\theta_0, \gamma_0)\right)}{\partial \left(\theta^T, \gamma^T\right)^T} = \begin{Bmatrix} G_\theta & G_\gamma\\ 0 & M\end{Bmatrix}$

This is easy to see but why is the inverse of $G$ this

$\widetilde{G}^{-1}  = \begin{Bmatrix} G_\theta^{-1} & -G_\theta^{-1}G_\gamma M^{-1}\\ 0 & M^{-1}\end{Bmatrix}$

I know that the derivative of a 2x2-Jacobian-matrix is if $J = \begin{Bmatrix} x_u & x_v\\ y_u & y_v \end{Bmatrix}$ where $x_u,...$ are the partial derivatives then $J^{-1} = \frac{1}{det\left(J\right)}\begin{Bmatrix} y_v & -x_v\\ -y_u & x_u \end{Bmatrix}$

But then $\widetilde{G}^{-1} = M^{-1}G_\theta^{-1}\begin{Bmatrix} M & -G_\gamma\\ 0 & G_\theta \end{Bmatrix} = \begin{Bmatrix} M^{-1}G_\theta^{-1}M & -M^{-1}G_\theta^{-1}G_\gamma\\ 0 & M^{-1} \end{Bmatrix}$

But this is not the same. **What have I done wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the formula for the inverse of $J$ has nothing to do with Jacobians, it is just the general inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Second, using the scalar expressions in the matrix context is extremely dangerous, as the matrix multiplication is not commutative, unlike the scalar multiplication (i.e., generally $AB \neq BA$). If you are not aware of this, you have very serious gaps in your math preparedness to tackle econometrics.

The inverse of a block matrix 
$$
M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}A & B \\ C & D\end{array}\right)
$$
is 
$$
M^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 A^{-1} + A^{-1} B P^{-1} C A^{-1} 
 & - A^{-1} B P^{-1}
 \\ - P^{-1} C A^{-1} 
 & P^{-1}
\end{array}\right), \quad P = D - CA^{-1} B
$$
or
$$
M^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 Q^{-1} 
 & - Q^{-1} B D^{-1} 
 \\ - D^{-1} C Q^{-1}
 & D^{-1} + D^{-1} C Q^{-1} B D^{-1} 
\end{array}\right), \quad Q = A - BD^{-1} C
$$
depending on which is easier to tackle. See Section 1.11 of [Magnus & Neudecker (1999)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047198633X) and/or Exercise 5.13 of [Abadir & Magnus (2005)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521537460). Once again, an econometrician must have at least one of these books within an arm's length.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I already figured it out and felt kinda dumb later on... but hey :)

Comment: You're welcome. Everybody gets brainblocks from time to time :).